# On the only eigen value of complex matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If suppose I have a square matrix with complex entries with all its  eigen value say, $\lambda$ which is real, than what are the possibility of such a matrix.
Now, if $\lambda $ is the only real eigen value than by Cayley-Hamilton Theorem we can conclude that $$(A-\lambda I )^n = 0 $$ .
Can we also say $$ A^n = \lambda^n I $$.

Comment: It's a nilpotent matrix

Answer (score 2):

You cannot conclude that. Take the matrix

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Clearly, the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $\lambda$ but $A \ne \lambda I$.

If $A$ is diagonalizable, then indeed you may conclude that $A = \lambda I$. For then $A = P(\lambda I)P^{-1} = \lambda PP^{-1} = \lambda I$. However, if $A$ is not diagonalizable, then it will have $1$'s on the super diagonal of its [Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) and as the above example shows, we cannot conclude $A = \lambda I$.